# What is the Immaculate Conception?

Tags: catholicism, virgin-mary, mariology, immaculate-conception

I know that Catholics believe in the Immaculate Conception. What is that?

Is this the same as the virginal conception of Jesus?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The Immaculate Conception is **not the same** as the miraculous conception of Jesus by the power of the Holy Spirit.

The Immaculate Conception refers to the **conception of Mary**: Mary was conceived (by her mother, Saint Anne) being **full of sanctifying grace and free of any stain of original sin**.

It does **not** refer to any of the following, which Catholics also uphold:

- Mary's freedom from any personal sin
- Mary's perpetual virginity
- The virgin birth of Jesus
- The virginal conception of Jesus (mentioned above)

---

From the [Baltimore Catechism](http://www.sacred-texts.com/chr/balt/balt3.htm):

> Q. 268. Was any one ever preserved from original sin?
>   A. The Blessed Virgin Mary, through the merits of her Divine Son, **was preserved free from the guilt of original sin**, and this privilege **is called her Immaculate Conception.**
>
> Q. 271. What does the "Immaculate Conception" mean?
>   A. The Immaculate Conception means the Blessed Virgin's own exclusive privilege of coming into existence, through the merits of Jesus Christ, without the stain of original sin. **It does not mean**, therefore, her sinless life, perpetual virginity or the miraculous conception of Our Divine Lord by the power of the Holy Ghost.

From the [Catechism of the Catholic Church](http://www.scborromeo.org/ccc/p122a3p2.htm#490):

> *The Immaculate Conception*
>
> 490 To become the mother of the Savior, Mary "**was enriched by God with gifts appropriate to such a role.**" The angel Gabriel at the moment of the annunciation salutes her as "full of grace". In fact, in order for Mary to be able to give the free assent of her faith to the announcement of her vocation, it was necessary that she be wholly borne by God's grace.
>
> 491 Through the centuries the Church has become ever more aware that Mary, "full of grace" through God, **was redeemed from the moment of her conception**. That is what the dogma of the Immaculate Conception confesses, as Pope Pius IX proclaimed in 1854:
>
> > The most Blessed Virgin Mary was, from the first moment of her conception, by a singular grace and privilege of almighty God and by virtue of the merits of Jesus Christ, Savior of the human race, **preserved immune from all stain of original sin**.
>
> 492 The "splendor of an entirely unique holiness" by which Mary is "enriched from the first instant of her conception" **comes wholly from Christ: she is "redeemed**, in a more exalted fashion, by reason of the merits of her Son". The Father blessed Mary more than any other created person "in Christ with every spiritual blessing in the heavenly places" and chose her "in Christ before the foundation of the world, to be holy and blameless before him in love".
>
> 493 The Fathers of the Eastern tradition call the Mother of God "the All-Holy" (Panagia), and celebrate her as "free from any stain of sin, as though fashioned by the Holy Spirit and formed as a new creature". **By the grace of God Mary remained free of every personal sin** her whole life long.

The Immaculate Conception does not imply that Mary did not need redemption through her Most Holy Son, Jesus Christ.

The Immaculate Conception is an Article of Faith among Catholics.

Answer (score 3):

One important point of belief of nearly every Christian fellowship and denomination is that Jesus Christ is the *perfect* sacrifice for our sins, and that this perfection is part of the reason His single sacrifice is able to cover the sins of so many. If Jesus were not perfect, his death would have been inadequate, and we are all lost.

This causes a small problem for those groups that believe in original sin: the idea that we inherit the guilt of Adam and Eve when they ate of the fruit of the Tree of Knowledge of Good and Evil. If Jesus also inherits this sin, he would no longer be the required perfect sacrifice.

Some such groups deal with this by concluding that this guilt is only passed down through the paternal line. Since Jesus had no biological father, he escapes original sin.

Catholics and some related groups believe that guilt is passed down both paternally and maternally. It's a side note, but this is probably a better interpretation, as Eve ate the fruit first... if you accept original sin at all (ie: Ezekiel 18:20). The Immaculate Conception refers to how Jesus escapes the guilt of his mother.

The idea of the Immaculate Conception is that Mary received special grace from the moment of her conception, such that at the time of her birth (and even through her entire lifetime) she was free from the burden of sin. This does not have to specifically mean that she never herself sinned (though many do believe this); it can also mean that she was in a state of special grace granted by God, sufficient to free Jesus from the original sin that He would have inherited from Mary. The important point is that when someone talks about Immaculate Conception, they're actually talking about *Mary*, and the reason why is the need for Jesus to not inherit original sin from his earthly mother.

It's also worth noting that there is no record, prophecy, or allusion to the Immaculate Conception anywhere in the Bible. The nearest is the "full of grace" expression in Luke ch. 1. However, the same phrase is used in a number of other places in scripture (Acts 6:8 and Colossians 4:6 for a start) for less-exalted purposes.

Comment: I thought it did mean that she never sinned, not because she didn't, but because she was free from the inclination to follow her passions which would lead her in to sin.

Answer (score 2):

The Immaculate Conception is that which is required if Mary is the new Eve (that is to say that Eve is a type of Mary).

The premise that Eve is a type of Mary as evidenced in Scripture appears to be accepted by early Christians.

St. Justin Martyr writes in the second century:

> [Jesus] became man by the Virgin, in order that the disobedience which proceeded from the serpent might receive its destruction in the same manner in which it derived its origin. For Eve, who was a virgin and undefiled, having conceived the word of the serpent, brought forth disobedience and death. (Dialogue with Trypho, 100)

St. Irenaeus of Lyon writes in the second century:

> And thus, as the human race fell into bondage to death by means of a virgin, so is it rescued by a virgin; virginal disobedience having been balanced in the opposite scale by virginal obedience. (Against Heresies, V.19.1)

St. Ephrem writes in the fourth century:

> With the body then that [was] from the Virgin, [Jesus] entered Sheol and plundered its storehouses and emptied its treasures. He came then to Eve the Mother of all living. This is the vine whose fence Death laid open by her own hands, and caused her to taste of his fruits. So Eve the Mother of all living became the well-spring of death to all living. But Mary budded forth, a new shoot from Eve the ancient vine; and new life dwelt in her, that when Death should come confidently after his custom to feed upon mortal fruits, the life that is slayer of death might be stored up [therein] against him… (Homily on Our Lord, 3)

St. Augustine writes in the fourth century:

> Our Lord . . . was not averse to males, for he took the form of a male, nor to females, for of a female he was born. Besides, there is a great mystery here: that just as death comes to us through a woman, life is born to us through a woman; that the devil, defeated, would be tormented by each nature, feminine and masculine, as he had taken delight in the defection of both. (Christian Combat 22.24)

The premise that the fulfillment of a type is always greater than the type itself is evidenced in Scripture and understood by most Christians. (See Matthew 13:52, 1 Corinthians 10:11, Hebrews 10:1, John 3:14.)

We can make a deductive argument from these two premises:

- Premise 1: Eve is a type of Mary.
- Premise 2: The fulfillment in the New Testament is always greater than the type in the Old Testament.
- Conclusion: **Mary is greater than Eve.**

We can make another deductive argument based on the conclusion:

- Premise 1: Eve was conceived (in the mind of God, i.e. created) without original sin (Genesis 2:22).
- Premise 2: Mary is greater than Eve.
- Conclusion: **Mary was conceived without original sin (the Immaculate Conception).**

Comment: Do Catholics explicitly teach that Eve was conceived??

Comment: @curiousdannii - I have heard the phrase "conceived in the mind of God." I don't know if that phrase is doctrinal.

Answer (score 1):

Holiness and immaculate conception of Mother Mary is a default necessity which directly stems from the purpose of God to save mankind from eternal death.

God had a plan to save his prized creation from the time  of Adam’s disobedience in Garden of Eden. That’s the reason God became man in Jesus Christ. In order that we might not suffer the penalty of our evil choices (sin), He, like a loving father, paid the penalty for our sins. He allowed his only begotten Son, Jesus Christ, to be born as human being, live an earthly life propagating His message of salvation.

God allowed his Son to be murdered on a Roman cross.  But this act of great evil gave rise to an even better state of affairs, and the greatest act of love in the universe: paying the penalty for the wrong choices we make, which were the result of the way He created us in the first place! In the cross of Christ He has provided a full pardon from the consequences of the evil in our lives.

For this purpose to fulfill, Jesus was to be brought in this world with a human nature and hence needed a human mother. But there was a problem. **A Son who is Divine in nature cannot come in a womb of a women who is defiled by the very nature as human beings**.

Precisely because of this reason, God at the instance of conception in St Anna’s womb, Blessed Virgin Mary was preserved free from all stain of Original Sin. This was done by a singular grace and privilege granted by Almighty God, in view of the merits (Divinity) of Jesus Christ, the Saviour of the human race “.

Mary, rather than being cleansed after sin, was completely prevented from contracting Original Sin in view of the foreseen merits of Jesus Christ, the Saviour of the human race.

This we say is the “Immaculate Conception” of Virgin Mary. That is she was sinless at the time of her birth.

In Luke 1:47, Mary proclaims:

> "My spirit has rejoiced in God my Saviour."

This is referred to as Mary's pre-redemption by Christ.

Answer (score 1):

Good answers all around, but let me add what the Blessed Virgin Mary herself said to St. Bernadette at Lourdes only a few years after the proclamation of the dogma:

> Que soi era immaculada concepcion

which is

> I am the Immaculate Conception

So, maybe the question shouldn't be what is the Immaculate Conception but who is the Immaculate Conception.